# Extracting 3 bytes to a number

Tags: c, bit, bitwise-operators

What is the FASTEST way, using bit operators to return the number, represented with 3 different `unsigned char` variables ?

```
unsigned char byte1 = 200;
unsigned char byte2 = 40;
unsigned char byte3 = 33;

unsigned long number = byte1 + byte2 * 256 + byte3 * 256 * 256;
```

is the slowest way possible.

Comment: Any decent compiler would make it the fastest (as shown in the answer given below).

Comment: I am wondering about the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shift each one into place, and OR them together:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t a = 0xAB, b = 0xCD, c = 0xEF;

    /*
     * 'a' must be first cast to uint32_t because of the implicit conversion
     * to int, which is only guaranteed to be at least 16 bits.
     * (Thanks Matt McNabb and Tim Čas.)
     */
    uint32_t i = ((uint32_t)a << 16) | (b << 8) | c;

    printf("0x%X\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Do note however, that almost any modern compiler will replace a multiplication by a power of two with a bit-shift of the appropriate amount.

Comment: UB if int is 16-bit :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Corrected, using `<stdint.h>`

Comment: I don't think that those types are Ansi-C.

Comment: The UB is due to `a << 16` - shifting by the width of the type (after integer promotions `a` becomes `int`) . You'd have to cast or otherwise promote `a` to `uint32_t`.

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing it on that way, the reason it didn't work was because I used different order. Thanks :) It is good to know that this is fast.

Comment: @barakmanos: `<stdint.h>` is part of C99. That said, the code is still UB because he's not actually casting `a` to `uint32_t` *before* shifting (only *after* shifting, implicitly). Only `a` has to be casted, because `int` is guaranteed to be *at least* 16-bit (and thus can *always* hold `b << 8`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Gosh is it a good thing I grew up in a wold of 32-bit `int`s :-)

Comment: @AlanSalios your compiler will generate the fastest code based on your intent, do not think things like 'well multiplying might be faster than shifting', the compiler knows what is fastest and will translate your code to use the fastest instructions

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yep although the same sort of issues would crop up with 32-bit and `a << 24`  (UB in this case - integer overflow, shifting into the sign bit).  I try to avoid shifts entirely because of it, my preference here is to use `a * 0x10000ul` although that is a bit less aesthetic

Comment: @MattMcNabb Appreciate the insight. So `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be 32 bits?

Comment: guaranteed to be at least 32, and it doesn't matter if it is bigger than 32 because unsigned arithmetic just drops excess bits safely. If we were making a 64-bit number then `ull` could be used (guaranteed at least 64).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, sorry I meant "at least". (`long` is 64 bits on Linux x86_64, 32 bits on Windows x86_64, for example). Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Logical pointer arithmetic must be a bit slower then bitwise though.

Comment: Performing logical arithmetic operations to a pointer. Where the size of the data type matters In that case, there is no pointer involved but still.

Comment: @AlanSalios: Indeed, there is no pointer here, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be the direct memory writing, assuming you know the endian of your system (here the assumption is little endian):

```
unsigned char byte1 = 200;
unsigned char byte2 = 40;
unsigned char byte3 = 33;

unsigned long number = 0;

((unsigned char*)&number)[0] = byte1;
((unsigned char*)&number)[1] = byte2;
((unsigned char*)&number)[2] = byte3;
```

Or if you don't mind doing some excercise, you can do something like:

```
union
{
    unsigned long ulongVal;
    unsigned char chars[4]; // In case your long is 32bits
} a;
```

and then by assigning:

```
a.chars[0] = byte1;
a.chars[1] = byte2;
a.chars[2] = byte3;
a.chars[3] = 0;
```

you will read the final value from `a.ulongVal`. This will spare extra memory operations.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but would it be *faster* doing 4 (cack-handed 8-bit) memory writes than doing (optimised) register operations and then 1 (natural size) memory write?

Comment: @weather vane I guess it can be optimized more using registers or even DMA, but it is becoming too platform dependant

Comment: Dynamically allocated pointers are proven to be accessed slower then the statically/automatically allocated ones.

Comment: @Alan Salios Which pointers are you talking about? BTW this claim sounds very doubtful to me.  Pointers, once allocated, have no difference. It is the same memory and the same operations. Maybe on some specific architectures the implementation might differ, but I haven't encountered one.